# Qualifying (and/or Quantifying) Internet Connectivity Problems

Tags: internet, home-networking, isp

I'm having intermittent problems with my internet, and would like to be able to give my provider enough information to help them diagnose the problem.

Is there a free tool I can run on my PC to track internet connectivity over time.  I'm not sure what it would measure--maybe ping or packet loss?  I have found tools online that allow you to ping or measure packet loss on demand, but nothing that constantly runs and logs uptime/downtime.

Does such a (free) tool exist?

Comment: As it stands now, this question is likely to be closed, being a software recommendation. If you change the wording so it doesn't get closed, you will likely get more answers. I will post one in a minute or two though to help

Answer (score 0):

You can use the built in `PING` command, available on virtually all OSes that support TCP/IP. But for it to be useful...

1. Plug the computer **DIRECTLY** into the modem
2. Know a well-known IP address or web server that you can ping
3. Collect the results to a file

Assuming you are using Windows, you can simply do something such as `PING www.google.com -t > %USERPROFILE%\PingTest.txt`; on *nix systems, `ping www.google.com > /home/username/pingtest.txt` or similar. The `-t` on the Windows side does an endless ping, only stopping for a <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>